# In Spring Data, How can I hint the hibernate affected table for native update sql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hazelcast

In spring data

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update user set name='abc'", nativeQuery = true)
int changeThemAll();
```

Due to `Modifying`, this query will invalid all cache, because hibernate can not find out the affected entities.
in `org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction#affectedEntity`, if there is no tablespace, will consider the table is affected.

This becomes problem

1. if the region is readonly, the hazelcast hibernate second level cache implemention will throw exception.
2. when there is a lot entries in cache, invalidate all table will affect the system

Also, I found this [article](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/08/impact-of-native-sql-queries-on-hibernates-second-level-cache/) described the solution for hibernate xml config.

The workaround I can think of is remove the `@Modifying`, and manual invalidate cache or use `JdbcTemplate` run the native sql and manual invalidate the cache.

Full stacktrace

```
at com.hazelcast.hibernate.access.ReadOnlyAccessDelegate.lockRegion(ReadOnlyAccessDelegate.java:72)
at com.hazelcast.hibernate.region.EntityRegionAccessStrategyAdapter.lockRegion(EntityRegionAccessStrategyAdapter.java:99)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction$EntityCleanup.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:209)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction$EntityCleanup.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:203)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.BulkOperationCleanupAction.<init>(BulkOperationCleanupAction.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.coordinateSharedCacheCleanup(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:152)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:176)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1373)
at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:373)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:405)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:238)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
```

Hazelcast `ReadOnlyAccessDelegate#lockRegion` implemention

```
@Override
public SoftLock lockRegion() throws CacheException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Attempting to lock a read-only cache region: "
            + getHazelcastRegion().getName());
}
```

**EDIT**

The question is how can I hint the hibernate affected table for native update sql.

e.g.

```
@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.QueryHints({
    @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.HINT_CACHE_REGION, value = "UserEntity"),
    // Something like this @QueryHint(name = QueryHints.HINT_AFFECTED_ENTITIES, value = "UserEntity"),
})
```

I can hint the cache region used for result, but how to hint the table spaces or affected entities ?

Relate methods

- org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomQuery#getQuerySpaces
- org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addSynchronizedQuerySpace
- org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addSynchronizedEntityName
- org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addSynchronizedEntityClass

Comment: You describe a problem and a solution. What is the question?

Comment: Hello @wener, i am facing the same issue. Can share what did you do to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hola @JensSchauder, based on the timestamp of the comment, i am guessing the *solution* or workaround as @wener puts it, is not to use `@Modifying`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace, I assume you're using read-only strategy for the region cache.

When you're using read-only as the caching strategy, you cannot update data in that region using Hibernate. As data in that region is not expected to  be updated, Hibernate second level cache providers don't implement `lockRegion` operation for read-only cache regions which is only used while invalidating the cache region.

I would suggest using a different caching strategy for that region (`read-write` might be possible), as you clearly need to modify data in that table.

Comment: There only few entities in read-only cache, we should keep that, instead I want to tell hibernate only invalidate the affected entity not all of them.Yes, I can change the cache to rw, but it's not what I want.